# Tkinter window to prevent PermissionError

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

I'm creating a script that will collect data and write it to a spreadsheet using openpyxl. Trying to save a workbook while it's open will result in a permissionError and remove all content from the clipboard without saving the document.

Since the script takes so long to execute, it can be a real headache if someone using it leaves the workbook open. To prevent this I am trying to implement a tkinter window that will tell the user to close the excel sheet in the event of a permissionError and remain open until they do.

I think I'm making this a bit over-complicated and I know this is not the best way to go about this. I would really appreciate any tips on how to do this the proper way. Here is the code as I have it now:

```
import openpyxl as op
import tkinter

class warning:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('WARNING')
        self.text = tkinter.Label(root, text = 'Please close spreadsheet, then press "Ok" to proceed.' )
        self.text.grid(row = 1)
        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
        self.button = tkinter.Button(self.frame, text = 'Ok', command = tryToSave(book, 'companies.xlsx')).grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.frame.grid(row = 2)

    def close(self):
        self.root.destroy()

def tryToSave(book, name):
    message = tkinter.Tk()
    functionality = warning(message)
    try:
        book.save(name)
        functionality.close()
    except PermissionError:
        message.mainloop()
        tryToSave(book, name)



book = op.load_workbook('C://Users/Alec/envs/RoboEmily/companies.xlsx')
tryToSave(book, 'C://Users/Alec/envs/RoboEmily/companies.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was overthinking this. Creating a class seems like a bit of overkill. I've re-written the original code as a simpler function.

```
import openpyxl as op
import tkinter       

def tryToSave(book, name):
    while 1:
        try:
            book.save(name)
            break
        except PermissionError:
            root = tkinter.Tk()
            message = tkinter.Label(root, text = 'Please close spreadsheet and click "ok"')
            message.grid(row = 1)

            ok = tkinter.Button(root, text = 'Ok', command = root.destroy).grid(row = 2)
            message.mainloop()

book = op.load_workbook('C://Users/Alec/envs/RoboEmily/companies.xlsx')
tryToSave(book, 'C://Users/Alec/envs/RoboEmily/companies.xlsx')
```

This will create a tkinter window instructing the user to close the spreadsheet and will persist until the spreadsheet is closed and the user clicks the 'ok' button. If they click that button before closing the sheet, the window will be destroyed and immediately re-created.

Answer (score 0):

So the only way that I can think of to have an *"automatic"* way of checking whether the file has closed is to output the contents of the task manager and parse through to see whether the file is open, but this seems horribly inefficient and poorly thought out.

A better solution (subjectively speaking) would be to use tkinter's `Toplevel` widget and have the user attempt to run the "Save" function again from the `Toplevel` if it fails initially.

I have created an example you can view below:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

        #Below we declare the "message window"
        self.top = Toplevel(self.root) #this creates the window
        self.top.withdraw() #this hides the window
        self.toplabel = Label(self.top, text="File is already open, please close first") #label for the window
        self.topsave = Button(self.top, text="Save", command=self.save) #button for the window

        #packing widgets for the toplevel
        self.toplabel.pack()
        self.topsave.pack()

        self.button = Button(self.root, text="Save", command=self.save)
        self.button.pack()

    def save(self):
        try:
            with open("file.csv", "w") as f: #we open the file pythonically
                f.write("Lorem ipsum") #we attempt to write to the file
                self.top.withdraw() #we attempt to hide the top level window
        except PermissionError:
            self.top.deiconify() #if we get a PermissionError exception, we try and unhide the window

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This creates a window with a save button. Once this button is pressed open the file and attempt to save to it. If the save fails then we unhide a window which we created earlier and also has a save button. Upon pressing this save button we run the same function (open the file, attempt to save, unhide window). If the function fails again, nothing visibly changes for the user. If the function succeeds then the file is saved to and the `Toplevel` window hides itself again.